# Load dll from a specific folder in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

i have Almost 15 Dll file that need to perform my application. i tried to use many cases. Embed Dlls all of this sort, not work as well.

So i ask can i make extra folder inside application directory to be for all my dlls that application need to run as well.

my code i created "Libs" folder inside Directory.location (application) , and i hope it will have all dlls that need to run application as well.("Application_Diretory\dlls\Libs")

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Reflection

Namespace My
' The following events are available for MyApplication:
' Startup: Raised when the application starts, before the startup form is created.
' Shutdown: Raised after all application forms are closed.  This event is not raised if the application terminates abnormally.
' UnhandledException: Raised if the application encounters an unhandled exception.
' StartupNextInstance: Raised when launching a single-instance application and the application is already active. 
' NetworkAvailabilityChanged: Raised when the network connection is connected or disconnected.
Partial Friend Class MyApplication
    Private Sub AppStart(ByVal sender As Object,
ByVal e As Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
        AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve, AddressOf LoadAssembly

    End Sub

    Private Function LoadAssembly(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As ResolveEventArgs) As Assembly
        Dim result As Assembly = Nothing

        String.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Name)
        'Get current exe fullpath
        Dim info As FileInfo = New FileInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.Location)
        'Get folder of the executing .exe
        Dim folderPath = Path.Combine(info.Directory.FullName, "dlls\Libs")
        'Build potential fullpath to the loading assembly
        Dim assemblyName = args.Name.Split(New String() {","}, StringSplitOptions.None)(0)
        Dim assemblyExtension = "dll"
        Dim assemblyPath = Path.Combine(folderPath, String.Format("{0}.{1}", assemblyName, assemblyExtension))
        'Check if the assembly exists in our "Libs" directory
        If File.Exists(assemblyPath) Then
            'Load the required assembly using our custom path
            result = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath)
        Else
            'Keep default loading
            Return args.RequestingAssembly
        End If

        Return result
    End Function

End Class
End Namespace
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you dont need all of them. !
you just need Edit your AppDomain.AppendPrivatePath, To be string.

```
Namespace My
Partial Friend Class MyApplication
Private Sub AppStart(ByVal sender As Object,
ByVal e As Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AppendPrivatePath("dlls\Libs")

End Sub
End Class
End Namespace
```

By this way all of your Dll's Will load.